# Passing the siraat bridge

Tags: day-of-judgement

Is there any text with respect to: Could it be the case that on the Day of Judgement, a person is in front of Allah, and when finished, he thinks that Allah forgave him, yet he falls down to Hell when passing the siraat bridge.

Or, is it the case that nobody will know whether he is forgiven or not, until actually passes that bridge?

Comment: no. some enter heaven by flying without even seeing the siraat bridge.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I have read quite the contrary in (Shia) Hadeeth that someone in the Judgement day will be accused and taken toward the hell, but in the way toward the hell the man acclaims Oh Allah! I had hope in your mercy, and wow Allah strangely enough accepts from him! and orders to his angels to else take him toward the Heaven, then adds that it is so although he knows that the man is only pretending! ... this is also somewhat implicitly stated in Quran where Allah says:

... لَا تَيْأَسُوا مِنْ رَوْحِ اللَّهِ إِنَّهُ لَا يَيْأَسُ مِنْ رَوْحِ اللَّهِ إِلَّا الْقَوْمُ الْكَافِرُونَ
... never give up hope of Allah's Soothing Mercy: truly no one despairs of Allah's Soothing Mercy except those who have no faith. (Joseph, 87)

وَ رَأَي الْمُجْرِمُونَ النَّارَ فَظَنُّوا أَنَّهُمْ مُوَاقِعُوهَا وَ لَمْ يَجِدُوا عَنْهَا مَصْرِفًا
And the Sinful shall see the fire and apprehend that they have to fall therein: no means will they find to turn away therefrom [alKahf, 53]

وَ يُعَذِّبَ الْمُنَافِقِينَ وَ الْمُنَافِقَاتِ وَ الْمُشْرِكِينَ وَ الْمُشْرِكَاتِ الظَّانِّينَ بِاللَّهِ ظَنَّ السَّوْءِ عَلَيْهِمْ دَائِرَةُ السَّوْءِ وَ غَضِبَ اللَّهُ عَلَيْهِمْ وَ لَعَنَهُمْ وَ أَعَدَّ لَهُمْ جَهَنَّمَ وَ سَاءَتْ مَصِيرًا
And that He may punish the Hypocrites, men and women, and the Polytheists men and women, who imagine an evil opinion of Allah. On them is a round of Evil: the Wrath of Allah is on them: He has cursed them and got Hell ready for them: and evil is it for a destination. (alFath, 6)

There are signs that evil imagination (or in some cases even some wrong imaginations) of Allah is the main reason to accuse people and their punishment.  Therefore, who ever can believe someone will hope in Allah's mercy and Allah will punish him in the hell? no way ...